# CQRS/ES Projection replay with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am using EF core as an ORM to which my ES events get played onto for the read-side of my CQRS application.

I have created a new feature that requires some modification of projections, and how they are represented. I wish to discard the current read model, and re-project the stream to rebuild the model.

The performance has been poor, as every time I create a new context, and persist it, looping over the events;

```cs
foreach (var event in events)
{
    using (var scope = _container.BeginScope('projection-scope'))
    using (var dbContext = scope.Resolve<MyDbContext>())
    {
        await scope.Resolve<IMediator>().Publish(event);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I am using DI containers to keep the persistance call out of the handler in an attempt to batch the projections and help improve performance, but am coming across increasing difficulty, with attached entities, relationships, and other SQL problems.

Is this a sound strategy, to bulk up multiple operations in an EF context, or is it better to ditch the ORM and go for a direct-SQL approach (maybe using dapper)?

Comment: Why do you need to recreate `DbContext` for every object? I feel like this is the bottleneck.

Comment: Same for `IMediator` - create once outside of the `events` loop

Comment: Introduces the snapshot concept. Please refer to https://eventflow.readthedocs.io/Snapshots.html

Comment: @idubnori this is for the read side, and aggregate snapshots are not in play here.

Comment: @trailmax this is for read-side projections. The circumstances in which they will need to be replayed will be rare, but there will be millions of events in some contexts. At the moment, I can get around 120/s but would like to get this much higher. The context creation is definitely the bottleneck here but I am having a tough time figuring out how to elegantly create/update entities. EF is relatively new to me and the abstraction may be more trouble than it's worth. Mediator is being used as a stand in for resolving the event projectors until I build something more adapted.

Comment: @DanielPark Try resolving DbContext every 100/200 records - that might help a little. However, EF is known to be slow on bulk-operations. And 120 ops/s is very slow. So if you are really getting a lot of operations to process, you might want to look on other ways to optimise - just for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a large amount of events, you should consider partitioning your event stream to create your projections in parallel. You can partition your stream based on AggregateId to allow your updates to process in serial within an Aggregate. Based on your current throughput and your desired throughput, you should be able to partition the stream to meet your requirements.

Additionally, since you are using event sourcing, I would say that EF is overkill from a logical perspective and certainly dragging you down from a performance perspective. You really just need a way to update the database based on an event. Simple ADO.NET would suffice in this case, presumably calling stored procedures. To avoid handwriting all of this code, you can generate it using t4 templates or another generator of your choice.

Comment: +1 in EF being overkill, at least from a projection standpoint. Looking into using ADO.net to perform read model updates, and EF for query support. This means I can use transactions to send bulk updates, and the updates can be done without building context/change tracking etc...

Comment: @DanielPark Yes, exactly. These are different tools with different use cases.